# Python: How can I fix this broken pipe error?

Tags: python, linux, pipe, ubuntu-14.04

I would like to limit the number of lines to displayed by the `tac` command by 5 and save this result in a new file.

```
tac /home/pi/log/log.txt | head -n 5
```

The command above works great in my command window...
however when I try calling it through a Python file and then save in a new file I get a `tac: write error: Broken pipe` error...

That is how the code looks like:

```
while True:
    db_file = open("/home/pi/log/heartbeat.txt", 'a')
    db_file.write('#################\n')
    db_file.write('LAST LOGs\n')
    db_file.write('#################\n')           
    db_file.close()

    statement = 'tac /home/pi/log/log.txt | head -n 5 '
    result = check_output(statement, shell=True)
    db_file = open("/home/pi/log/heartbeat.txt", 'a')
    db_file.write(result)
    db_file.close()
    sleep(1)
```

By the way, I am using the command `watch` every second to keep checking the new content.

Any hints on how can I get this fixed?

Thanks,

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem; what OS are you using?

Comment: Note that it may be wise to first close the file before running `tac` on it, and then open it again for appending afterwards.

Comment: Hi Evert. I did some changes based on your comments. I am using ubuntu14.04 for testing purposes but my objective is to run it in a Raspbian. After making the changes you suggested, I am getting much less errors however I am getting a new one 'tac: write error' (without the broken pipe). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this error with this modeification to your statement command:

**Change from:**

```
statement = 'tac /home/pi/log/log.txt | head -n 5 '
```

**Change to:**

```
statement = 'tail -n5 /home/pi/log/log.txt | tac | head -n 5 '
```

**Also, the statement can be shortened with:**

```
statement = 'tail -n5 /home/pi/log/log.txt | tac'
```

The error is happening because (and will only manifest in certain environments such as your immediate python environment) when the limit that stops the reading is triggered during the buffer read cycle.  It won't happen on a smaller file because the content would be read before the trigger closes the the `tac` command.

The error isn't fatal... just a nuisance.  It can be ignored, or you can use the workaround provided.

Answer (score -1):

I think tac will work bad on large inputs, so maybe it's better to change your command to :

```
tail -n5 /home/pi/log/log.txt | tac
```

(Will tac gets crashed when working on your large log file in a python env and causes the broken pipe error?)